# Can't figure out paste by values Google sheets macro

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've tried many different ways - I just can't get the text to paste by values in its cell. The resulting output is blank of PASTE_VALUES and just a formula if PASTE_NORMAL.

Help appreciated.

Many thanks
AB

```
function testMacro() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();

  for (var counter = 1; counter <= 5; counter = counter + 1) {
  ss.getRange('C4').activate();
  var row = 24 + counter;
  ss.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=B'+row);
  ss.getRange('C'+row).activate();
  ss.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=J3');
  ss.getRange('D'+row).activate();
  ss.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=J4');
  ss.getRange('C'+row+':D'+row).activate();
  ss.getRange('C'+row+':D'+row).copyTo(sh.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);

  }
```

Comment: Can you provide a visual example of what your data looks like and what your expected results are because the logic of your macro has me completely stumped.  You do something in `C4`, then you put the same formula in C25:C30 and D25:D30, then you copy it somewhere. By the time all that is done I'm not sure what the `getActiveRange` is.

Comment: What I want to do is change parameter of my model by increments of 100 and record the results in a table.

Cell C4 is the parameter i want to change
Cell B25 (to B##) have the values i want to set Cell C4
Cell J3 and J4 contain the results of the model once parameter is changed in C4
I want to paste J3 to C25 (to C##) and J4 to D25 (to D##)
I then want to paste by values so the history of the results stay
I then move to the next row.